# Adding Fortran syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2017 via TextMate system

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, fortran, textmatebundles

This link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/adding-visual-studio-editor-support-for-other-languages?view=vs-2017

Suggests I should be able to add syntax highlighting for .for files in Visual Studio 2017. I have added the Fortran TextMate Grammar to my user profile as the article suggests, but I can't get any highlighting to work.

Is there some missing step? Do I need to do something in VS2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, and it's a little dumb, but so others don't fall into the same trap... I had .for files open in my solution and kept just re-opening it to see if the highlighting was working. This would automatically reopen the files that were last open in the solution, but wouldn't highlight them...until I closed and reopened the .for files.

D'oh!